# Cases relationship in salesforce?

Tags: case, servicecloud, case-object

Cases in salesforce are customer’s question or feedback on the service they are providing.

Eg. if a company sell a product A. Then A will be added to opportunitylineItem. When we have a problem with product we need to log a case on a particular opportunitylineItem. **But in standard salesforce service cloud case have lookup to contact and Account**.

I am not able to understand if a Account have more than opportunity then how it identified to which product the case been loged (In standard salesforce service cloud). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cases can't have links to Opportunity Line Items directly. However, there are two fields you can expose, Asset and Product, which allows you to link to a specific product, or an asset, which is an instance of a product that belongs to an account or contact.

Generally speaking, upon winning an opportunity, assets should be created for the account in order to note which products they actually have. This would also allow you to specify things like serial numbers, product, and custom attributes specific to your line of business. Some companies do this manually, some have written code to do this automatically, and some do not track this data at all (but, for most companies, I'd say that they probably *should* track this information).

In fact, if you are using assets, you can go to an account, locate the appropriate asset, and click the New Case button to automatically start a new case for that specific product. When everything is set up, creating a new case from the asset page will populate the account, contact, asset, and product for you automatically. This can greatly reduce the complexity needed to start a new case. Of course, it would also be possible to use other methods, like a Visualforce page, etc to populate this data, but can definitely be done out of the box with minimal effort required.

Comment: But in the case of web to case and email to case do we need to have a separate trigger to associate the case to an account.  I am getting confused if a case is added to Account then the service team have to do a search for which product the case been loged, am i right.

Comment: There is also ServiceContract with child ContractItems, items can point at products.

Comment: @Anu Yes, you'd have to capture the data in to a custom field and then perform your lookup somehow. However, that said, using web to case, I don't know how'd you expect the average customer to get it right to begin with. You might want to look into better alternatives, like a Sites page, or a Portal, or a custom auto-complete service, or anything that gives you more control than Web to Case does.

Answer (score 1):

Case does not has direct standard relationship with Product object. There is standard object "Asset" which does this work.

There are two ways you can keep track of product for which the Case is logged.

1. Create picklist on Case object and enter product code there. But that will increase the manual work as you will always have to update the multi-picklist when product is added. But advantage is that you can keep track Case related to multiple products on single record.
2. You can create lookup relationship field Product and Opportunity on Case object and associate product and opportunity with that case. Here only one product can be associated with one case. But Case object have self relationship so, it can be utilized.

Comment: If i go and add a case under a Account manually then their is no connection with opportunity and product in standard service cloud. In this case service team have to do a manual search for which product the case been loged, am i right.

Comment: Yes, There is no direct connection between a case and product or opportunity. In out of the box approach 'Asset' object is used to track this. But Asset don't have direct relationship with Opportunity. Hope this helps. @Anu

Comment: @Ashwani There is a case product field, actually. You just have to put it on your layout/enable field security.

Comment: @sfdcfox I knew that but couldn't found in org when checked. I checked in winter 16 org. It even not mentioned in SOAP docs Case object. It should be there from Spring 10 release. May be I have missed something.

Comment: It's possible. Odd it's not in the manual, but I have several orgs that have it. I don't think I have any that do not. Maybe products are not enabled in your org? A bug maybe?

Comment: @sfdcfox checked in two dev orgs, one is partner dev. These is no standard field Product. However, I see custom product__c picklist type field everywhere. I checked product settings too. There is nothing which can be disabled. Very strange!

Comment: I know I'm not crazy though: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bra4 I really wonder what's up with this. Further research is warranted. Thanks for pointing that out.